# How to plot 2 graphics in one picture?

Tags: matlab

I have the following code to plot one graphic:

```
plot(softmax(:,1), softmax(:,2), 'b.')
```

and then this one to plot another:

```
plot(softmaxretro(:,1), softmaxretro(:,2), 'r.')
```

Now I'd like to be able to plot both ones in the same place. How can I accomplish that?

Comment: do you mean on the same set of axes or side-by-side in one figure?

Comment: Same set of axes, so I can better compare them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Solution#1: Draw both set of points on the same axes

```
plot(softmax(:,1),softmax(:,2),'b.', softmaxretro(:,1),softmaxretro(:,2),'r.')
```

or you can use the `hold` command:

```
plot(softmax(:,1), softmax(:,2), 'b.')
hold on
plot(softmaxretro(:,1), softmaxretro(:,2), 'r.')
hold off
```

#### Solution#2: Draw each on seperate axes side-by-side on the same figure

```
subplot(121), plot(softmax(:,1), softmax(:,2), 'b.')
subplot(122), plot(softmaxretro(:,1), softmaxretro(:,2), 'r.')
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [HOLD command](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/hold.html) so that the second plot is added to the first:

```
plot(softmax(:,1), softmax(:,2), 'b.');
hold on;
plot(softmaxretro(:,1), softmaxretro(:,2), 'r.');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also plot one on top of the other be slightly editing @amro's solution #2:

> subplot(121), plot(softmax(:,1),
>   softmax(:,2), 'b.') subplot(122),
>   plot(softmaxretro(:,1),
>   softmaxretro(:,2), 'r.')

becomes

subplot(211), plot(softmax(:,1), softmax(:,2), 'b.')
subplot(212), plot(softmaxretro(:,1), softmaxretro(:,2), 'r.')