# Coloring a plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a 1x400 vector, I want to draw each 80 elements in different color with `plot` command, first 80 elements in blue, second 80 elements in green and so so.

Comment: I mean it should be continues drawing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way is to reshape the data so that you plot multiple columns simultaneously, like this:

```
x = 1:400;
y = x.^1.5;
plot(reshape(x,80,5), reshape(y,80,5))
```

If you need more control, you can either use the `line` command, or plot with `hold on`.

Answer (score 3):

There's two ways to do this:

(1) Reshape your vector so that it's a 80-by-5 array and call `plot` once

```
plot(reshape(yourVector,80,5))
```

(2) [Use `hold on` to make sure plots get added, not replaced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1858039/how-to-plot-2-graphics-in-one-picture/1858068#1858068)